# Dual circuit with diode

Tags: ltspice, thevenin

Looking for a rectifier made up from an inductor instead of a capacitor, I came to this question.

The circuits on the figure are dual each other, in the Thévenin Norton sense, with capacitor voltage and inductor current, the results are the same.

[image]

[image]

After adding an Ideal Diode, I am unable to find some close analogy of that dual.

Considering an Ideal Diode is only a switching device, though non linear, I could assume that dual could exist. Anybody have a good estimate on how to find that dual?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider to get a fair analogy between the two circuits you may think to replace the diode by a [constant-current diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-current_diode) since the characteristics are equivalent when we interchange voltage with current:

[image]

and hence replacing the voltage source with a current source:

[image]

Think also to consider components in parallel instead of serial.

Comment: I figured that the Dual of the Voltage Source with an Ideal Diode in series should be a Current Source with an Ideal Diode in parallel. For an Ideal Diode I think it would not matter. For a Less Than Ideal Diode, this would be the solution.